# Equivalent of plist in Android

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I have developed an application on native `iOS` platform where I was reading user settings from the plist.

```
string settingsBundle = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource ("Settings.bundle/Root", @"plist");
NSDictionary dic = NSDictionary.FromFile (settingsBundle);
```

I wonder what is the common way of doing it in the `Android` or `Xamarin.Android`

Comment: A plist is just XML.

Comment: how could I add `server name`, `userid`, `port` in the XML and read from there? If you could provide a simple example, I would be glad.

Comment: Check out SharedPreferences: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put default user settings in preferences.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="pref_sync"
        android:title="@string/pref_sync"
        android:summary="@string/pref_sync_summ"
        android:defaultValue="true" />
    <ListPreference
        android:dependency="pref_sync"
        android:key="pref_syncConnectionType"
        android:title="@string/pref_syncConnectionType"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/pref_syncConnectionType"
        android:entries="@array/pref_syncConnectionTypes_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_syncConnectionTypes_values"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_syncConnectionTypes_default" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

and read it like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String syncConnPref = sharedPref.getString(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_SYNC_CONN, "");
```

See more details at [Defining Preferences in XML](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#DefiningPrefs)